# Getting an empty array, when uploading a file with vuejs and axios in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to upload an image, following this [link from Yubaraj](https://jsfiddle.net/meyubaraj/fLbe7r72/) but upon submission, the image file is an empty object.

Of which according to Yubaraj is actually what you should put the server.

What he is done is actually hide a normal input file behind a text-field and gets the data with an event.

Here is a snippet on the two events:

```
pickFile () {
            this.$refs.image.click ()
        },

        onFilePicked (e) {
            const files = e.target.files
            if (files[0] !== undefined) {
                this.form.imageName = files[0].name
                if (this.form.imageName.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) {
                    return
                }

                const fr = new FileReader();
                fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    this.form.imageUrl = fr.result;
                    this.form.imageFile = files[0] // this is an image file that can be sent to server...
                })
            } else {
                this.form.imageName = '';
                this.form.imageFile = '';
                this.form.imageUrl = '';
            }
        },
```

When I console log the form.image.file, and the file, this is what I get from the browsers console:

[image]

using vform post which actually uses axios behind the scenes.
    this.form.post(route('api.settings.branch.create'), this.form)

an image of the dd() result from the network tab in the browser: 
[image]
the very much text there is the dataurl of the image

Comment: Can we see the server-side implementation?

Comment: actually, from the server, I've only written a dd(request()->all()) which gives me the imageFile as an empty array

Comment: Can we see how you are actually uploading the file (the axios part)?

Comment: added it above, the the form object is from vform which contains all the form data values

Comment: Shouldn't your post just be `this.form.post(route('api.settings.branch.create'))`?

Comment: the form there has the data

Comment: Even if it has the data, isn't it already an instance of `new Form()` which means you can just chain `.post()` to it? In any case `.post()`'s third parameter is an array of axios config. Not form data.

Comment: let me try removing it and see

Comment: still the same, the imageFile is an empty array

Comment: Did you take a look at the [form upload](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html) example in their github repo? Maybe that could help?

Comment: nope, let me look at it